# Html: Video card img a hover

Tags: html, css

hello I want to have a "how" when I go over the picture but the heart is positioned elsewhere. where is the mistake?

and the point I don't understand is why does my card width seem to be overflowing?

Because of the overflow I showed in the picture. When I add a card to the 2nd card. The cards are coming upside down.
[image]
[image]

```css
.card-video {
            width: 305px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .card-pic img {
            object-fit: cover;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 305px;
            max-height: 170px;
        }


        .card-info-logo {
            position: absolute;
            right: 5px;
            top: -28px;
        }

        .card-info-logo img {
            width: 55px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 4px solid #5e4b55;
        }

        .card-info {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #292828;
            height: 90px;
            padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .card-info-top {
            flex: 1;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .card-info .card-info-category {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .card-info .card-info-title {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .card-info-bottom {
            border-top: solid 1px #44393e;
            padding-top: 7px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            line-height: 1;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .card-info .card-info-bottom .views {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 12px;

        }

        .card-info .card-info-bottom .date {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .card-pic {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }

        .clip-icon {
            position: relative;

        }

        .clip-icon:hover {
            background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<div class="card-video">
<div class="card-pic">
    <a href="">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VeDmG7YovSM/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="clip-icon">
            <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="card-info mt-1">
    <div class="card-info-logo">
        <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxBc7gQx7gKOeJG0uTgpfZVUA1FT_EOxjVjYtI-=s100-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-top">
        <div class="card-info-category">Video Category</div>
        <div class="card-info-title">Video Title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-bottom">
        <div class="views">312K</div>
        <div class="date">16 hour ago</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.card-video is having flow direction column.
If you try to put the more card like this it will always show in upside down like a stack. Wrap the entire thing in div and provide the flow-direction: row and flex-wrap : wrap to get desired result.

```html
<style>
  .box{ 
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
     flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
  .card-video {
            width: 305px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin:0.5rem;
        }

        .card-pic img {
            object-fit: cover;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 305px;
            max-height: 170px;
        }


        .card-info-logo {
            position: absolute;
            right: 5px;
            top: -28px;
        }

        .card-info-logo img {
            width: 55px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 4px solid #5e4b55;
        }

        .card-info {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #292828;
            height: 90px;
            padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .card-info-top {
            flex: 1;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .card-info .card-info-category {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .card-info .card-info-title {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .card-info-bottom {
            border-top: solid 1px #44393e;
            padding-top: 7px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            line-height: 1;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .card-info .card-info-bottom .views {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 12px;

        }

        .card-info .card-info-bottom .date {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .card-pic {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }

        .clip-icon {
            position: relative;

        }

        .clip-icon:hover {
            background-color: red;
        }

  </style>
  <div class="box">
<div class="card-video">
<div class="card-pic">
    <a href="">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VeDmG7YovSM/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="clip-icon">
            <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="card-info mt-1">
    <div class="card-info-logo">
        <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxBc7gQx7gKOeJG0uTgpfZVUA1FT_EOxjVjYtI-=s100-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-top">
        <div class="card-info-category">Video Category</div>
        <div class="card-info-title">Video Title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-bottom">
        <div class="views">312K</div>
        <div class="date">16 hour ago</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card-video">
<div class="card-pic">
    <a href="">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VeDmG7YovSM/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="clip-icon">
            <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="card-info mt-1">
    <div class="card-info-logo">
        <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxBc7gQx7gKOeJG0uTgpfZVUA1FT_EOxjVjYtI-=s100-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-top">
        <div class="card-info-category">Video Category</div>
        <div class="card-info-title">Video Title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-bottom">
        <div class="views">312K</div>
        <div class="date">16 hour ago</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</box>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. but I think you forgot the img hover thing.

Comment: where we have to place heart when we are hovering over the image

Comment: I couldn't quite guess how. When your friend does it, it's not exactly centered. I added a new image.

Answer (score 0):

The flex-direction needs to be set to row, with flex-wrap:wrap as to format correctly.

The `.clip-icon` can be set to `position:absolute` if the parent element has `position:relative` applied.

You can set the `clip-icon` to `display:none` and get it to display on picture hover by adding `.card-pic:hover .clip-icon: { display:block; }`

I have added a snippet below

```css
.box{ 
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
     flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
  .card-video {
            width: 305px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin:0.5rem;
        }

        .card-pic img {
            object-fit: cover;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 305px;
            max-height: 170px;
        }


        .card-info-logo {
            position: absolute;
            right: 5px;
            top: -28px;
        }

        .card-info-logo img {
            width: 55px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 4px solid #5e4b55;
        }

        .card-info {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #292828;
            height: 90px;
            padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .card-info-top {
            flex: 1;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .card-info .card-info-category {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .card-info .card-info-title {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .card-info-bottom {
            border-top: solid 1px #44393e;
            padding-top: 7px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            line-height: 1;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .card-info .card-info-bottom .views {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 12px;

        }

        .card-info .card-info-bottom .date {
            color: #546e7a;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        
        .card-pic:hover .clip-icon{
            display:block;
        }

        .card-pic {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            position:relative;
        }
        .clip-icon a {
          position: relative
        }
        .clip-icon {
            position: absolute;
     
            bottom:10px;
            left:5px;
            width:20px;
            height:20px;
            background-color:white;
            display:none;

        }

        .clip-icon:hover {
            background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="card-video">
<div class="card-pic">
    <a href="">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VeDmG7YovSM/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="clip-icon">
            <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="card-info mt-1">
    <div class="card-info-logo">
        <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxBc7gQx7gKOeJG0uTgpfZVUA1FT_EOxjVjYtI-=s100-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-top">
        <div class="card-info-category">Video Category</div>
        <div class="card-info-title">Video Title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-bottom">
        <div class="views">312K</div>
        <div class="date">16 hour ago</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card-video">
<div class="card-pic">
    <a href="">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VeDmG7YovSM/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="clip-icon">
            <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="card-info mt-1">
    <div class="card-info-logo">
        <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxBc7gQx7gKOeJG0uTgpfZVUA1FT_EOxjVjYtI-=s100-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-top">
        <div class="card-info-category">Video Category</div>
        <div class="card-info-title">Video Title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-info-bottom">
        <div class="views">312K</div>
        <div class="date">16 hour ago</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</box>
```

Comment: I wanted the image I wanted to be in the middle of the picture, not like this